# Pandas counitfs equivalent

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am stuck in trying to convert excel COUNTIFS function with pandas.
I have a big df, like the following (two columns, with columns names "C2_C5" and "Mn")

```
C2_C5 Min
-0.4 0.2
-0.3 0.3
-0.4 0.2
0.4 2
0.3 1.8
0.3 1.6
0.1 2
0.4 1.8
-0.2 0.2
-0.1 0.4
-0.1 0.4
-0.3 0.3
0.1 2
0.3 1.6
```

I want an output like this

```
Bins: **0 0.5, 1.5, 2.0**
**-0.4**, 0,2,0,0
**-0.2**, 0,3,0,0
**0**,    0,2,0,0
**0.2**,  0,0,0,2
**0.4**,  0,0,0,5
```

where:
the first row (0 0.5 1.5 2.0) and he first column (-0.4 -0.2 0 0.2 0.4) are user-defined bins for df[Min_Dist] and df[C2_C5] columns respectively.
while the remaining values represent the counts of each pairs where both bins are satisfied.

My code is as follow:

```
A1=df[(df['C2_C5'] <=-0.4) & (df['Min_Dist'] <= 0.0)]['C2_C5'].count()
A2=df[(df['C2_C5'] <= -0.4) & (df['Min_Dist'] >0) &(df['Min_Dist'] <=0.5)]['C2_C5'].count()
A3=df[(df['C2_C5'] <= -0.4) & (df['Min_Dist'] >0.5) &(df['Min_Dist'] <=1.5)]['C2_C5'].count()
A4=df[(df['C2_C5'] <= -0.4) & (df['Min_Dist'] >1.5) &(df['Min_Dist'] <=2.0)]['C2_C5'].count()

B1=df[(df['C2_C5']  > -0.4) & (df['C2_C5'] <= -0.2)  & (df['Min_Dist'] <=0.0)]['C2_C5'].count()
B2=df[(df['C2_C5']  > -0.4) & (df['C2_C5'] <= -0.2)  & (df['Min_Dist'] >0) &(df['Min_Dist'] <=0.5)]['C2_C5'].count()
B3=df[(df['C2_C5']  > -0.4) & (df['C2_C5'] <= -0.2)  & (df['Min_Dist'] >0.5) &(df['Min_Dist'] <=1.5)]['C2_C5'].count()
B4=df[(df['C2_C5']  > -0.4) & (df['C2_C5'] <= -0.2)  & (df['Min_Dist'] >1.5) &(df['Min_Dist'] <=2.0)]['C2_C5'].count()

C1=df[(df['C2_C5']  > -0.2) & (df['C2_C5'] <= 0.0)  & (df['Min_Dist'] <=0.0)]['C2_C5'].count()
C2=df[(df['C2_C5']  > -0.2) & (df['C2_C5'] <= 0.0)  & (df['Min_Dist'] >0) &(df['Min_Dist'] <=0.5)]['C2_C5'].count()
C3=df[(df['C2_C5']  > -0.2) & (df['C2_C5'] <= 0.0)  & (df['Min_Dist'] >0.5) &(df['Min_Dist'] <=1.5)]['C2_C5'].count()
C4=df[(df['C2_C5']  > -0.2) & (df['C2_C5'] <= 0.0)  & (df['Min_Dist'] >1.5) &(df['Min_Dist'] <=2.0)]['C2_C5'].count()


D1=df[(df['C2_C5']  > 0) & (df['C2_C5'] <= 0.2)  & (df['Min_Dist'] <=0.0)]['C2_C5'].count()
D2=df[(df['C2_C5']  > 0) & (df['C2_C5'] <= 0.2)  & (df['Min_Dist'] >0) &(df['Min_Dist'] <=0.5)]['C2_C5'].count()
D3=df[(df['C2_C5']  > 0) & (df['C2_C5'] <= 0.2)  & (df['Min_Dist'] >0.5) &(df['Min_Dist'] <=1.5)]['C2_C5'].count()
D4=df[(df['C2_C5']  > 0) & (df['C2_C5'] <= 0.2)  & (df['Min_Dist'] >1.5) &(df['Min_Dist'] <=2.0)]['C2_C5'].count()

E1=df[(df['C2_C5']  > 0.2) & (df['C2_C5'] <= 0.4)  & (df['Min_Dist'] <=0.0)]['C2_C5'].count()
E2=df[(df['C2_C5']  > 0.2) & (df['C2_C5'] <= 0.4)  & (df['Min_Dist'] >0) &(df['Min_Dist'] <=0.5)]['C2_C5'].count()
E3=df[(df['C2_C5']  > 0.2) & (df['C2_C5'] <= 0.4)  & (df['Min_Dist'] >0.5) &(df['Min_Dist'] <=1.5)]['C2_C5'].count()
E4=df[(df['C2_C5']  > 0.2) & (df['C2_C5'] <= 0.4)  & (df['Min_Dist'] >1.5) &(df['Min_Dist'] <=2.0)]['C2_C5'].count()

arr = [[A1, A2, A3, A4],
       [B1, B2, B3, B4],
       [C1, C2, C3, C4],
       [D1, D2, D3, D4],
       [E1, E2, E3, E4],
      ]


pre_heat = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=['0', '0.5', '1.5', '2.0'])
Bins= (['-0.4','-0.2', '0', '0.2', '0.4'])
pre_heat['Bins'] = Bins
first_column = pre_heat.pop('Bins')
pre_heat.insert(0, 'Bins', first_column)
pre_heat= pre_heat.set_index('Bins')
pre_heat

pre_heat.to_csv('TEST.TXT')
```

It works but every time I want to increase or decrease the bins number for each column is very time consuming.

Basically I have to mimic the excel COUNTIFS function with numerical data range as bins
Can you help me with a smarter solution?

Many thanks!

Comment: Kindly provide the output in a cleaner form without the asterisks. Like a proper dataframe output

Comment: and if you can, kindly explain the logic, for someone like me not familiar with countifs

Comment: Hello, sure that is the output:
```
Bins,0,0.5,1.5,2.0
-0.4,0,2,0,0
-0.2,0,3,0,0
0,0,2,0,0
0.2,0,0,0,2
0.4,0,0,0,5
```

Comment: the logic of COUNTIFS is to count cells based on just  multiple criteria (in my case I have two columns, each with its proper bins) with AND logic.